# Passing Databricks ClusterID at runtime from Azure Data Bricks Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am looking to make Azure linked service configurable and hence passing the Databricks WorkspaceURL and the ClusterID at runtime. I will be having multiple Spark cluster and based on the size of the cluster I would be invoking the type/size of the cluster.

I am not finding an option of getting the DataBricks ClusterID and passit from the ADF pipeline

[image: Databricks Linked Service]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API [Clusters API 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters#example-9)  to get cluster list.

```
https://adb-7012303279496007.7.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/list
```

I have reproduced the above and got the below result.

First generate the access token in databricks workspace and use that in **web activity** as authorization to get the list of clusters.

[image]

**Output from web activity:**

[image]

The above also contains cluster size in mb. Store the above in an array variable.

[image]

For getting the desired cluster id based on cluster size you can use your filter condition as per your requirement.

Here, for sample I have used cluster size in mb as filter condition.

[image]

**Notebook linked service:**

parameter for cluster_id.

[image]

Pass the desired cluster_id from filtered array like below.

```
@activity('Filter1').output.Value[0].cluster_id
```

[image]

You can give the Notebook path using the dynamic content.

[image]

**My Execution:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, looking promising. I think I will add another web activity to pull the bearer token from the keyvault and then pass it to the Cluster API List to identify the cluserid. I will mark it as accepted answer. Thanks again